# Zapier code XMLHttpRequest() says XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Tags: zapier

Hello I want to make a request to a xml file for a value I want on Code by Zapier, but I get the error `XMLHttpRequest is not defined`. I also tried `var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;` but it says `Error: Cannot find module 'xmlhttprequest'`.

Answer (score 1):

While the XMLHttpRequest is available in most browsers, it is not distributed in Node, which is what the Code action is using. Specifically, the Javascript code action is running a Node v10.x.x environment. You can see all of the commands and methods supported by that environment here:

https://node.green/

The JS environment does support the Fetch library for making requests. Perhaps you can look into making this work?

https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch